# How can I access the 3rd argument of _safeMint?

Tags: solidity, erc-721, calldata, mint, data

I am minting an ERC721 using `_safeMint` and I am setting the 3rd argument to a `string`. I want to be able to access this `data` argument using the transaction hash or whatever I have to access the blockchain and check for this information.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nice to meet you.

To access the data argument of an ERC721 token minted using _safeMint, you can use the following steps:

1. Get the transaction hash of the minting transaction.
2. Use the transaction hash to query the blockchain for the transaction receipt.
3. The transaction receipt will contain a field called "logs".
4. The "logs" field will contain an array of events that were emitted during the transaction.
5. One of the events in the "logs" field will be the ERC721's "Transfer" event.
6. The "Transfer" event will contain a field called "data".
7. The "data" field will contain the data argument that was passed to the _safeMint function.

Here is an example of how to access the data argument of an ERC721 token minted using _safeMint:

```
const txHash = "0x1234567890abcdef1234567890abcdef1234567890abcdef";

const receipt = await web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(txHash);

const logs = receipt.logs;

const transferEvent = logs.find((log) => log.event === "Transfer");

const data = transferEvent.args.data;

console.log(data); // Output: "This is the data argument"
```